# SaaS provider wanting Single-Signon, do I need to integrate with several Identity Providers?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, saas

I work for a SaaS provider that is wanting to SSO enable our application to enterprise customers with our application acting as the service provider.

I understand the concepts behind what needs to happen and that SAML is an  appropriate solution for what we are looking to do.  Looking at bigger SaaS providers (slack, dropbox, new relic etc..) I can see they typically seem to integrate with a number of Identity Providers such as OneLogin, Bitium, Okta, Ping Identity etc... along with generic SAML support

As a smaller outfit we don't have the resources to partner and integrate with multiples of ID providers and to continue to add to that list as new providers emerge.

My question is that in order to provide SAML support in our application do I really need to have integrations with multiple IDPs or can I rely on a generic SAML implementation?

So if for example I used OneLogin to set up Single Sign On does that only enable SSO for clients who are using One Login as their Identity Provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is not required IMHO. As long as you are SAML 2.0 compliant (SP-Lite typically), you'll find that you'll have customers using many different commercial (and open source) Identity Provider solutions. The vast majority of SaaS vendors have not done anything specific to support different IDP implementations. The SaaS supports the SAML 2.0 spec and ends up having customers integrating successfully with the different (IDP) products. At that point they claim to "support" the different providers.

Adhere to the spec as best you can and the rest will take care of itself.

Comment: I have a couple of questions. 1) If your application is SAML compliant then you only have to ask for SAML endpoint/entityID  from the IDP and your application do not have to undergo any changes to support the IDP 2) Is the same true fo OpenID?

Comment: 1) Yes. For SP-Init SSO you'll need the IDP endpoint for sending AuthNRequests. You'll also want the public cert/key from the IDP to validate signatures. 2) OpenID Connect - Yes.